# RSS News Feed API

Tags: api, rss

I have an idea for a new project that would require me to get the news feeds from many RSS news feeds. I am unable to find a free or affordable API that lets me do this. All I have found is NewsCred, which is significantly too expensive for me. It doesn't seem practical for me to manually input the feeds of 2000 different newspapers both from a time standpoint, and due to potential legal-related licensing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com/)? (I created it!). We provide an API that will do the fetching, parsing and and diffing of all the feeds you supply, in realtime.

The main difference with NewsCred is that you are the one picking your sources and supplying them to us. We accept *any* kind of RSS/Atom feed and already power services like [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) for example.